# Deployment of Angular App to Azure Storage Account fails with connection timeout

Tags: angular, azure, sass

We have an Angular app hosted on Azure Storage Account and that has been working well for a long time, but for the last 2-3 months or so it’s been hit and miss deploying updates.

We deploy from GitHub Actions to a public Storage Account, and we receive the following error almost every time now we want to deploy the app.

```
Preparing for deployment
preparing static deploy
Error when trying to deploy: 
request to https://<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/%24web/assets%2Fscss%2Fcore%2Fmixins%2F_utilities.scss?comp=blocklist failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.150.66.4:443
```

The only way we eventually get this fixed is by manually deleting the file. It’s always a different file, and we might delete this one, and the next attempt fails on a different file, we retry a few times, and it might work eventually.

Is there a way for us to not include the `scss` folder in our source and have this done client side? (I'm not necessarily a frontend person)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to deploy Angular App to Azure Storage Account using GitHub Actions.

- In local, create a new Angular Web App.

Thanks @[JohannesHoppe](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages) for the `npm commands`.

```cs
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new myAngJan24
```

[image]

- Navigate to the application root directory.

```cs
cd myAngJan24
ng serve
```

[image]

- Run `ng build --prod` , `dist` folder will be created with the content of output files.
- Push the application from `local` to `GitHub Repository`.
- Create a new `Storage Account`.

[image]

- Create a container in it.

[image]

- Add the secrets in the [GitHubRepository.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-static-site-github-actions?tabs=userlevel#generate-deployment-credentials)
- Now manually we need to create a workflow file with Azure CLI commands.

> Preparing for deployment
> preparing static deploy
> Error when trying to deploy:

- Make sure the `dist` folder with content exists in the Repository.

This can also be the reason if the Storage Account has any Network Groups.

If it has any make sure it has the permission for outbound connection for the specific Storage Account.

> Is there a way for us to not include the `scss` folder in our source and have this done client side?

While creating the App, you will get an option to select the `stylesheet format`. Instead of `SCSS` choose `CSS` option.

[image]

- If you have already developed the application and want to change it now. Then we have an option of [sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader).
- We just need to import the `SASS` file in our angular component.

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-static-site-github-actions?tabs=userlevel)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As I said however, the deployment already works, it just intermittently fails. It has worked for over 2 years, never got changed, and about 3 months ago it started failing intermittently.